# user role to be only allowed access and auto logged into the admin backend from ip address

Tags: administration

I have employees who use a specific admin back end role, so i want the user role to be only allowed access and if possible to be auto logged into the admin back end from ip address when they visit the admin back end url

i have the main super admin and i want to make sure this will be normal and can use the admin back end as normal from any ip

Answer (score 0):

Warning: **Ip adress is not a security feature.**

Create a new folder inside public folder and make it private.
Don't know if you have a CPanel or what ever to make this work.

Than create a NEW index.php and .htaccess.....

Inside index.php of private folder:

```
Mage::app(...., ....., $options....)

Mage::getModel('admin/session')->login($username, isset($password) ? $password : '');
Mage::unregister('controller');

Mage::run(...., ....., $options....)
```

And bob's your uncle.

So take away: **Never create your own security logic.** Just use the security features you already have. If unknow, ask your server administrator. And better sollution, is hire better employees that can use a login form and are smart enough to remember there password.